# how to use MenuItem in another MenuItem in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I want to make a menu like this in wpf

[image]

I wrote this code:

```
<MenuItem Header="Menu 4" MouseEnter="mousecom" Background="DarkGreen">
       <MenuItem.ContextMenu>
             <ContextMenu>
                   <MenuItem Header="submenu 1"/>
                   <MenuItem Header="submenu 2"/>                   
             </ContextMenu>
       </MenuItem.ContextMenu>
 </MenuItem>
```

and `mousecom` is:

```
private void mousecom(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            while (IsMouseOver)
            {
                (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
                (sender as Button).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (sender as Button);
                (sender as Button).ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Right;
                (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
            }           
        }
```

I mean I wanna have a MenuItem and by coming mouse on it another menu opens including some other MenuItems.

Why it doesn't work?

how can I do that?
(please pay attention to the picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `MenuItem` control incorrectly.

To create submenus, you would do something like the following:

```
<!-- Top level menu -->
<MenuItem>

    <!-- Level 1 menu -->
    <MenuItem>

        <!-- Level 2 menus -->
        <MenuItem />
        <MenuItem />
        <MenuItem />
    </MenuItem>

    <!-- More level 1 menus -->
    <MenuItem />
    <MenuItem />
    <MenuItem />
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: thank you...you solved one of my biggest problems :)